# Javascript regex retrieve variables from sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, nlp

I'm wondering if it's possible to extract a number of variables from a predefined sentence with regex or similar.

e.g.

If this was the pattern...

```
"How many * awards did * win in *?"
```

And someone typed...

```
"How many gold awards did johnny win in 2008?"
```

How can I somehow return...

```
["gold","johnny","2008"]
```

I'd also like to return the fact that it matches the pattern before retrieving the variables as there will be many different patterns. Note: It will also be possible for someone to type multiple words in place of a * e.g. *johnny english* instead of just *johnny*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Derek's answer and SimpleCoder's comment, here would be the full function:

```
// This function escapes a regex string
// http://simonwillison.net/2006/jan/20/escape/
function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

function match(pattern, text) {
    var regex = '^' + escapeRegex(pattern).replace(/\\\*/g, '(.+)') + '$';
    var query = text.match(new RegExp(regex, 'i'));
    if (!query)
        return false;

    query.shift(); // remove first element
    return query;
}

match("How many * awards did * win in *?", "How many gold awards did johnny win in 2008?");
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks Derek and Casey. These functions work a treat. I am also considering porting this to PHP too. Are there similar regex features in PHP? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = "How many gold awards did johnny win in 2008?";
var query = text.match(/^How many ([^\s]+) awards did ([^\s]+) win in ([^\s]+)\?$/i);
query.splice(0,1); //remove the first item since you will not need it
query[0] //gold
query[1] //johny
query[2] //2008
```

For more information, see [MDN - match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

### UPDATE

Seems like you want to match `johny english` in `How many gold awards did johnny english win in 2008?`.
This is a updated version of the regex:

```
/^How many (.+) awards did (.+) win in (.+)\?$/i
```

Comment: To add to this, you could dynamically build the regex by replacing the `*` character with `([^\s]+)` given a pattern string.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - And change every `?` into `\?`

Comment: Yep, and other special characters too :)

Comment: [The match function docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: For the sake of slight simplification, `([^\s]+)` is the same as `(\S+)`.